# Git pull/fetch with refspec differences

Tags: git, git-pull, git-fetch

Using refspec is a convenient way to grab a remote branch and create a similar one but with given name (or the other way round: create a remote one with a given name different from the local one). I'm puzzled about one tiny thing - as pull will also do the merge with current branch I would expect different behavior from:

```
git fetch origin master:mymaster
```

and from

```
git pull origin master:mymaster
```

**Both of the above commands seem to produce exactly same result** - that is a local branch called mymaster, same as origin/master. Am I right or is there a vague difference between the two?

Finally, using a refspec will create a *local* branch **not** a *tracking* branch, right? Since tracking branches are pushed automagically when one invokes git push without any arguments AFAIK

Comment: Would it really be exactly the same result though? I would expect `pull` to merge `origin/master` to local `master`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A refspec is just a source/destination pair. Using a refspec `x:y` with `fetch` tells git to make a branch in this repo named "y" that is a copy of the branch named "x" in the remote repo. Nothing else.

With `pull`, git throws a merge on top. First, a fetch is done using the given refspec, and then the destination branch is merged into the current branch. If that's confusing, here's a step-by-step:

```
git pull origin master:mymaster
```

1. Go to origin and get branch "master"
2. Make a copy of it locally named "mymaster"
3. Merge "mymaster" into the current branch

Fully qualified, that would be `refs/heads/mymaster` and `refs/heads/master`. For comparison, the default refspec set up by git on a clone is `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`. `refs/remotes` makes a convenient namespace for keeping remote branches separate from local ones. What you're doing is telling git to put a remote-tracking branch in the same namespace as your local branches.

As for "tracking branches", that's just an entry in your config file telling git where to pull and push a local branch to/from by default.

Answer (score 4):

`git fetch origin master:mymaster` updates branch mymaster in the local repository by fetching from the master branch of the remote repository.

`git pull origin master:mymaster` does above and merges it into the current branch.

Answer (score 0):

git fetch origin master:mymaster

However, the command must meet the following two conditions strictly:

1. The local current branch cannot be mymaster.
2. The local mymaster branch is the ancestor of origin/master.

then will make fast-forward merge. Otherwise it will report a fatal.

When both of the above conditions are true, execute the command:

```
git pull origin master:mymaster
```

In addition to executing the command:

```
git fetch origin master:mymaster
```

Will also execute：

```
git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

Notice：not git merge mymaster

FETCH_HEAD is different from mymaster， because mymaster maybe already fast-forward merge.

Answer (score -1):

I had used smartgit to create branch, so might be at that branch doesn't properly merged into master. 
Created support branch for release ie support/4.2, tag automatically get created but now wehn I try to do git pull, it shows me same error. 
As support/4.2 brannch is created in github but not properly merged in local. 
So I have used this :- 
git pull origin master:mymaster

In my case - git pull origin support/4.2:support/4.2

It works :)