# git merge pull branches confusion

Tags: git, git-branch, bitbucket, git-merge, git-pull

I have 2 branches (master and dev). Another worker has pushed a new branch called stage into the repository so that stage is now 1 commit ahead of master. I am trying to pull down stage so that I can merge it into master (and thus merge into dev), but I am having issues pulling down stage. How do I pull down a clean version of stage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you understand the branching basics of Git here. You may understand a bit more after reading my answer, by example.

#### the long story

You should fetch all updates

```
git fetch --all
```

then you should see the now still remote branch:

```
git branch -a
[...]
remotes/origin/stage
```

*Optionally*, you can make this branch a local branch `stage` (does not have to have the same name) by checking it out

```
git checkout -b stage origin/stage
```

And you should be switched onto this branch with this.

Now back to master and merge it:

```
git checkout master
git merge origin/stage # or just 'stage' if you have it local
```

#### the pull magic

Now, one could combine both `fetch` and `merge` steps by a single `pull`. However, sometimes it's needed to fetch new branches and their heads in order to be able to specify them.

```
git pull origin stage
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin stage
```

Considering `master` isn't linked to `stage` at all, you need to specify from where you are pulling, and what you are merging.
See:

- "[`Git pull/fetch` with refspec differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169103/git-pull-fetch-with-refspec-differences)"
- "[`git - push current` vs. `push upstream` (tracking)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751319/git-push-current-vs-push-upstream-tracking/13751847#13751847)" for more.

Comment: origin/stage , tried to add as an edit, but apparently 6 characters are needed to fix a syntax issue.

Comment: @sjakubowski `git pull origin stage` is like `git pull origin master:stage` here: it merges the remote branch `stage` in the current branch, as shown in the example section of `git pull`: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#_examples