# git fetch non fast forward update

Tags: git

I know that `git fetch` always does a fast forward merge between the branch and it's remote tracking after it fetches the commits from the remote.

My question deals with a scenario in which we will be requiring `git fetch` to do a non fast forward merge. Is it possible to make git fetch non fast forward merge ?
If not , how will I solve this below scenario ?

### My local repo (made some 2 local commits - the C and B commit)

```
...--o--o--A   <-- origin/master
            \
             C--B   <-- master
```

### After that I run git fetch (to update my branch)

```
...--o--o--A-- D  <-- origin/master (updated)
            \
             C--B   <-- master
```

Here , `origin/master` needs to be merged in master but this won't be fast forward. `git fetch` will fail. I don't want force fetch as I don't want to lose my commits `C` and `B` also.

How can I make git fetch to make a non fast forward merge. Something like this :

```
...--o--o--A-- D --  
            \      \
             \      F <-- master ,origin/master (updated) (my merge commit for non fast forward)
              \    /
               C--B
```

Comment: Fetch does not merge. Only pull merges.

Comment: fetch merges remote tracking and branch by fast forward update. pull merges the local branch updated with the current branch. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50545041/git-pull-with-refspec

Comment: `git pull --no-ff origin master`. In some cases, `origin` and `master` can be omitted. And @Christoph is right.

Comment: @ElpieKay , so we cannot do with git fetch alone ?

Comment: We can, but fetch does not merge. `git pull` is equal to 2 steps, `git fetch origin master && git merge --no-ff FETCH_HEAD`.

Comment: Read this https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Comment: @ElpieKay  , I think either u or phd ans is wrong here. As far as I get, fetch does a fast forward update  merge on branch and it's remote tracking branch. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50545567/2844702
As far as my question is concerned , I am trying a non fast forward merge with remote tracking branch . `git merge --no-ff FETCH_HEAD` is for current branch where my HEAD is. I did not mentioned what is my current branch.

Comment: If you don't want to update your remote tracking branch, you could directly run `git merge origin/master`. If you need to update it first, then fetch and merge. I don't know where you learned that "fetch does a fast forward update merge". Here is the manual of `git fetch`, https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch.

Comment: see this ans : stackoverflow.com/a/50545567/2844702 
 (in comment)'git fetch origin branchB:branchC` does fast forward merging! If it couldn't it would fail with an error message.

Comment: Such syntax `git fetch origin branchB:branchC` can succeed only in a fast-forward merge when 1) the tip of the local `branchC` is an ancestor of the tip of the remote `branchB`, and 2) the local `branchC` is not checked out yet. In your case neither condition is true and instead `git fetch origin master && git merge FETCH_HEAD --no-ff` can always do the job perfectly. I don't understand why you insist the wrong approach.

Comment: Sorry I missed something from your comments. If `master` is not the current branch, a non-fast-forward merge can't succeed by `git fetch`. Check it out first and then merge.

Comment: In fact the error comes from the fact you'r developping in "master" branch. If you had a dev-branch , then when you fetch master then update local master, no impact on your dev-branch, then you rebase the dev-branch and everything stays find. then when you finish your dev ; you can merge your dev-branch (if you rebased it before it should be FF)

Comment: `git fetch` does not merge. Period.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

(Note: I started writing this early this morning, and finished it late this evening; the question was answered in between, but having done all this work I'm still going to post the answer. :-) )

#### TL;DR

The `git fetch` command never merges anything.  It can update references, and is very willing to update branch-like references in a fast-forward fashion.  It is more reluctant to update such references in a non-fast-forward fashion; to do so, you must *force* the update.

Fast-forwarding—once properly divorced from the idea of merging—is a property of a *change to a reference that refers to a commit*.  More specifically, we're usually interested in whether a branch name value, or a remote-tracking name value, changes in a fast-forward fashion.  This means that we must look at the *commit graph*, because it's the *new place in the commit graph*, combined with the commit *currently selected* by the reference, that determines whether the update to that reference is a fast-forward.

#### Long

The original claim here is wrong, in at least one important way:

> I know that `git fetch` always does a fast forward merge between the branch and it's remote tracking after it fetches the commits from the remote.

Let's take this apart a bit, so that we have the right words and phrases to use.  We need to know:

- what a *reference* is;
- what a *refspec* is; and most importantly,
- what it means to do a *fast-forward* update vs a *non-fast-forward* update to a reference.

This last bit also involves the *force flag:* each reference update can be forced, or non-forced.  You may be familiar with `git push --force`, which sets the force flag for *every* reference that Git is pushing.  The `git fetch` command has the same flag, with the same effect—but in general "all or nothing" is too broad, so Git has a way to set the force flag on a more individual basis.  (The `git push` command has even more refinements here, but we'll only mention them in passing.)

#### Definition of *reference* and *refspec*

A *reference*, in Git, is just a name—ideally, a name that makes sense to a human—for some specific commit or other Git object.<sup>1</sup>  References always<sup>2</sup> start with `refs/` and mostly go on to have a second slash-delimited component that declares which kind of reference they are, e.g., `refs/heads/` is a *branch name*, `refs/tags/` is a *tag name*, and `refs/remotes/` is a *remote-tracking name*.<sup>3</sup>

(The references we care about here, for deciding whether some update is or is not a fast-forward, are those that we would like to behave in a "branch-y manner": those in `refs/heads/` and those in `refs/remotes/`.  The rules we will discuss in a moment *could* be applied to any reference, but *are definitely* applied to these "branch-y" references.)

If you use an unqualified name like `master` where Git either requires or could use a reference, Git will figure out the full reference, using the six-step procedure outlined near the beginning of [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) to resolve the abbreviated name to a full name.<sup>4</sup>

A *refspec*, in Git, is mostly a pair of references separated by a colon (`:`) character, with an optional leading plus sign `+`.  The reference on the left side is the *source*, and the reference on the right is the *destination*.  We use refspecs with `git fetch` and `git push`, which connect two different Git repositories.  The source reference is meant for the use of whichever Git is sending commits and other Git objects, and the destination is meant for the use of the receiving Git.  For `git fetch` in particular, then, the source is the *other* Git, and the destination is ourselves.

If a reference in a refspec is not fully qualified (does not start with `refs/`), Git can use the process above to qualify it.  If *both* references in a single refspec are unqualified, Git has some code in it to attempt to put them both into an appropriate name-space, but I've never trusted this code very much.  It's not clear to me, for instance, who really qualifies the source and destination during a fetch: there are two Gits involved, but the other Git usually sends us a complete list of all of their references, so our Git could do the resolving using this list.  It's obviously wiser to use fully-qualified references here, though, in case *their* set of references does not match your own expectations: if they have only a `refs/tags/xyz` and you were expecting `xyz` to expand to `refs/heads/xyz`, you can be surprised when it doesn't.

In any refspec, you can omit either the source or the destination part.  To omit the destination, you write the refspec without a colon, e.g., `refs/heads/br`.  To omit the source, you write the refspec with a colon, but with nothing where the source part would go, e.g., `:refs/heads/br`.  What it *means* when you do these things varies: `git fetch` treats them very differently from `git push`.  For now, just note that there are the source and destination parts, with the option of omitting them.

The leading plus, if you choose to use it, always goes at the front.  Hence `git push origin +:refs/heads/br` is a push with the force flag set, of an empty source, to the destination `refs/heads/br`, which is fully-qualified.  Since this is a push, the source represents our Git's name (none) and the destination represents their Git's name (a branch named `br`).  The similar-looking string `+refs/heads/br` has the force flag set, has a fully-qualified source, and has no destination.  If we were concerned with `git push` we could look at the meanings of these two refspecs for push, but let's move on now.

---

<sup>1</sup>Any branch-like reference *must* point to a commit.  Tag names may point to any object.  Other reference names may have other constraints.

<sup>2</sup>There's some internal disagreement within Git itself whether *every* reference must be spelled, in its full-name form, as something matching `refs/*`.  If that were the case, `HEAD` would never be a reference.  In fact, the special names like `HEAD` and `ORIG_HEAD` and `MERGE_HEAD` sometimes act like normal references, and sometimes don't.  For myself, I mostly exclude these from the concept of reference, except whenever it's convenient to include them.  Each Git command makes up its little Gitty mind about how and whether to update these `*_HEAD` names, so there's no formal systematic approach like there is—or mostly is, given the *other* weird special cases that crop up in some commands—for `refs/` style references.

<sup>3</sup>There are more well-known sub-spaces: e.g., `refs/replace` is reserved for `git replace`.  The idea here, though, is simple enough: `refs/` is followed by another human-readable string that tells us what kind of reference this particular reference is.  Depending on the kind, we might demand yet another sub-space, as is the case in `refs/remotes/` where we next want to know: which remote?

<sup>4</sup>Some Git commands know, or assume, that an abbreviated reference *must* be a branch name or a tag name.  For instance, `git branch` won't let you spell out `refs/heads/` in some places: it just rudely shoves `refs/heads/` in on its own, since it *only* works on branch-names.  The six-step procedure is generally used when there's no clear *must be a branch name* or *must be a tag name* rule.

---

#### The commit graph

Before we can define what it means to do a *fast-forward update*, we need to look at the *commit graph*.  Fast-forward vs non-fast-forward only makes sense in the context of commits and the commit graph.  As a result, it only makes sense for references that refer specifically to *commits*.  Branch-like names—those in `refs/heads/` and those in `refs/remotes/`—do always point to commits, and those are the ones we care about here.

Commits are uniquely identified by their hash ID.<sup>5</sup>  Every commit also stores some set of *parent* commit hash IDs.  Most commits store a single parent ID; we say that such a commit *points to* its parent commit.  These pointers make up a backwards-looking chain, from most-recent commit to oldest:

```
A  <-B  <-C
```

for instance, in a tiny repository with just three commits.  Commit `C` has commit `B` as its immediate parent, so `C` points to `B`.  Commit `B` has commit `A` as its immediate parent, so `B` points to `A`.  `A` is the very first commit made, so it has no parent: it is a *root commit* and it points nowhere.

These pointers form an ancestor / descendant relationship.  We know that these pointers always look backwards, so we don't need to draw the internal arrows.  We *do* need something to identify the *tip* commit of the data structure, though, so that Git can find the *ends* of these chains:

```
o--o--C--o--o--o--G   <-- master
       \
        o--o--J   <-- develop
```

Here `master` points to some commit `G`, and `develop` points to `J`.  Following `J` backwards, or `G` backwards, eventually leads to commit `C`.  Commit `C` is therefore an *ancestor* of commits `G` and `J`.

Note that `G` and `J` have no parent/child relationship with each other!  Neither is a descendant of the other, and neither is a parent of the other; they merely have some common ancestor once we go far enough back in time / history.

---

<sup>5</sup>In fact, *every* Git object is uniquely identified by its hash ID.  This is, for instance, how Git stores only one copy of some file's contents even when that particular version of that one file gets stored in dozens or thousands of commits: commits that don't change the file's contents can re-use the existing blob object.

---

#### Definition of *fast-forward*

Fast-forward-ness is a property of *moving a label*.  We can move the existing names (`master` and `develop`) around, but let's avoid doing so for a moment.  Suppose, instead, we add a new name, and make it point to commit `C`.  Let's add one-letter hash IDs for the rest of the commits as well:

```
        ............ <-- temp
       .
A--B--C--D--E--F--G   <-- master
       \
        H--I--J   <-- develop
```

We can now ask Git to move the new name from commit `C` to any other commit.

When we do so, we can ask another question *about* this move.  Specifically, `temp` *currently* points to commit `C`.  We pick another ID out of the `A`-through-`J` universe of possible commits and tell Git to *move* `temp` so that it points to this newly selected commit.  Our question is simple: **Is the new commit a descendant of the commit to which the label points right now?**

If this label-move results in the name `temp` pointing to a commit that *is* a descendant of `C`, this move *is* a fast-forward.  If not—if we pick commit `B` or `A`—this move is *not* a fast-forward.

That's it—that's *all* a fast-forward is.  It's the answer to the question of whether *this update* to *this label*, that we are about to do *right now*, results in the label *moving forward* along some chain of our backwards-pointing commits.

The reason this is particularly interesting for *branch* names—names in the `refs/heads/` space—is that `git commit` creates a *new* commit whose parent is the *current* commit, and adds this new commit to the graph—and then *updates the current branch name* to point to the new commit it just made.  A repeated series of `git commit` operations therefore results in a one-step-at-a-time forward motion of the branch label.  For instance, if we check out `develop` and make two new commits, we get:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G   <-- master
       \
        H--I--J--K--L   <-- develop
```

with the name `develop` now pointing to the second of these new commits.

If, while fiddling with `temp`, we made our branch-name `temp` point to commit `J`, we could now *fast-forward* `temp` to point to commit `L`.  Because `L` points back to `K` which points back to `J`, all Git operations that follow these chains will treat commit `K` as still being "on" branch `temp`.  So fast-forwarding is interesting because it means we don't "lose" commits.

On the other hand, if we made `temp` point instead to `E`, moving `temp` now to point to `K` will "lose" commits `D` and `E` from branch `temp`.  Those commits are still safely on `master`, so they are still protected here.  If they weren't on `master` any more for some reason—for instance, if we did something odd or unusual to `master` such as deleting the branch name—*then* commits `D` and `E` would be protected via the name `temp` up until the point we yank `temp` around in a non-fast-forward fashion.  If `temp` is the *only* name protecting those commits from the garbage collector, they become vulnerable.

#### Comparing fast-forwarding to what *to merge* means, as a verb

Git does have something it calls a *fast-forward merge*.  I dislike the phrase "fast-forward merge" since it's not really a merge at all—it's much more like just running `git checkout`, except for the fact that a branch name moves.  But [the `git merge` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) uses the phrase, after more formally saying that some *merge resolves as a fast-forward*, so we have to be able to interpret it.

A *fast-forward merge* in Git results from running a `git merge other` where *`other`* is a commit that is strictly ahead of (i.e., is a descendant of) the current or `HEAD` commit in the graph.  This means that the branch *name* to which `HEAD` is attached can be moved in a fast-forward fashion.  For instance, with branch name `temp` pointing to commit `C`, we could run:

```
git checkout temp
git merge <hash-of-commit-E>
```

Git will realize that moving the label `temp` from commit `C` to commit `E` is a fast-forward operation on that label.  The primary thing that allows us to use the verb *merge* here is the fact that we just used `git merge` to achieve it: the `git merge` command therefore updates our *index and work-tree* as well as doing the fast-forward operation.

But this is just `git merge` borrowing the concept of fast-forwarding.  Fast-forwarding is not itself a "merge-y" concept.  If you run a different `git merge other` where *`other`* is *not* a descendant of the current commit, but *is* a descendant of some *common ancestor* of the current commit—i.e., of a merge-base—then, in this case, `git merge` performs a true merge, using your index and work-tree as areas in which to do the merging.  *That* is a merge, an operation that really fills the shoes of the verb phrase *to merge*.

(We have no such commit in our graph—we'd have to make a child of `A` or `B`, after which commit `A` or commit `B` would be the merge base.)

#### Neither `git fetch` nor `git push` ever merge

As we just noted, a real merge requires—at least potentially—the use of the index and work-tree.  The `git fetch` command *does not* touch the index and work-tree.  A `git push` is often done to a `--bare` repository, which does not even *have* a work-tree!

A `git fetch` or `git push` operation *can* do fast-forwarding.  Since fast-forwarding *isn't* merging, this doesn't contradict our "never merge" claim.  A `git fetch` or `git push` operation can also do *non-fast-forward* operations on reference names, including branch names, but to do so, the *force flag* must be enabled on that particular operation.

(The `git push` command offers not just "plain" and "force" but also "force-with-lease", which is analogous to a compare-and-swap or CAS instruction in multithreaded programming.  The fetch command does not have this CAS option, it has only plain-or-forced.)

#### How `git fetch` uses refspecs to update references

The `git fetch` command has (at least, depending on how you count) two parts:

- transfer *commits* (and other Git objects) from another Git into our Git, augmenting our commit graph;
- optionally, update some *references* in our repository.

It has the side effect of writing *everything* it knows about new commits into `.git/FETCH_HEAD`, which is a special file that definitely is not a reference—there's never any ambiguity about this, unlike `HEAD`—but does contain hash IDs (plus extra information about what our Git saw from the other Git).  The rest of Git can use the data left in this file, even if `git fetch` does not update any references.

Now, remember that a refspec can list a both source reference and a destination reference, or just a source, or just a destination.  It can also have a leading `+` sign to indicate "force if necessary".

Looking specifically at `git fetch`, then, when dealing with what is to happen in the second half, we have these three possible cases:

- refspec with both source and destination: use the source to locate a name in the other Git repository; use the destination to choose a name to update in our own repository.
- refspec with source but no destination: use the source to locate a name in the other Git repository, but don't update any local name (but see below).
- refspec with destination but no source: error.

In very old versions of Git—those before Git version 1.8.4—a `git fetch` operation simply obeys whatever refspecs you give it on the command line. If you give it no refspecs, it uses and obeys the `remote.remote.fetch` directives in the configuration.  That is, in these old versions of Git, running `git fetch origin xyz` fetches whatever reference `xyz` matches, and since there is *no* destination, this updates *no* reference in our own repository!  (The command still writes information to `.git/FETCH_HEAD`, as it always does.)  Note that `xyz` might be a tag: the other Git might find `refs/tags/xyz` and not `refs/heads/xyz`.  We did not specify; if we want to be sure to fetch a *branch* we need to specify `refs/heads/`.

If your Git is at least version 1.8.4, though, when `git fetch` brings over a *branch* name, Git does an *opportunistic update* using your `remote.remote.fetch` fetch settings.  So, assuming the normal `remote.origin.fetch` setting, `git fetch origin refs/heads/xyz`:

- updates nothing, because of the empty destination part;
- but then updates `refs/remotes/origin/xyz`, because of the `fetch` setting.

Once `git fetch` gets around to doing all of its updates, each update:

- can succeed because the rules for this kind of reference allow the update, or
- can fail because the rules don't allow it and the force flag is not set; or
- can succeed because even though the rules don't allow it, the force flag is set.

Suppose, then, that we run:

```
git fetch origin refs/heads/xyz:refs/heads/abc
```

and that there *is* a `refs/heads/xyz` on the other Git at `origin`.  Suppose further that our Git is at least 1.8.4 and we have the usual refspec in `remote.origin.fetch`.  Then our Git:

1. Brings over the commits that go with their Git's `refs/heads/xyz` if necessary.
2. Attempts to update our `refs/heads/abc`.  This update is *not* forced.  This update is due to what we told our Git on the command line.
3. Attempts to update our `refs/remotes/origin/xyz`.  This update *is* forced.  This update is due to what we told our Git through `remote.origin.fetch`.

Since both `refs/heads/` and `refs/remotes/` are branch style name-spaces, our Git—which we know is at least 1.8.4—follows the *branch update rules* here.<sup>6</sup>  These tell Git that an update is *automatically* allowed *if it's a fast-forward*.

For item 2 here, the name to be updated is `refs/heads/abc` (because that's on the right side of the refspec on the command line).  Again, *fast-forward* here has nothing to do with merging: Git just checks whether the current value of `refs/heads/abc` is an ancestor of the proposed new value of `refs/heads/abc`.  If so, this update is allowed.  If not, it's not.

For item 3, the name to be updated is `refs/remotes/origin/xyz` (because the name matched on the left was `refs/heads/xyz` and the default refspec reads `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`).  This refspec *has the force flag set*, so the update to `refs/remotes/origin/xyz` *will* happen.  It will be a normal, fast-forward, non-forced update if the change is a fast-forward.  It will be a non-fast-forward forced update if the change is a non-fast-forward.

---

<sup>6</sup>In Git 1.8.2 and earlier, Git accidentally applies the branch update "must be a fast forward operation" rules to tag names as well.  In Git 1.8.4, this was fixed.  However, [a new bug was introduced at some point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41815610/1256452).  The code inside Git to update references during `git fetch` is horrible and twisty and I think probably should be thrown away and re-coded from scratch, but actually doing that is a nightmare of its own.

---

#### There's one more special constraint in `git fetch`

We noted in passing above that the special name `HEAD`, which probably is not a reference, is usually *attached to* some branch name.  When your HEAD is attached to some branch, that branch is your *current branch*.  That's the internal definition of what it means to *have* that branch as your current branch: the branch's name has to be inside the `.git/HEAD` file.

By default, `git fetch` *refuses to update this branch name*.  That is, if `HEAD` is attached to `master`, `git fetch` simply won't update `refs/heads/master`.  Running `git fetch origin refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master` will fail to update your `refs/heads/master`.  After you `git checkout` some *other* branch, attaching `HEAD` to `develop` for instance, *then* `git fetch` is willing to update `master`, and *now* you can run `git fetch origin master:master` (assuming you prefer the shorter, slightly riskier, unqualified spelling) if you like.<sup>7</sup>

The *reason* for this special constraint has to do with the difference we noted above about how `git merge` does a merge that resolves in a fast-forward: `git merge` *updates the index and work-tree*, as if you ran `git checkout`.  The `git fetch` command *never* updates the index and work-tree.  If `git fetch` allowed you to fast-forward your `master` to a new commit, your index and work-tree could get [out of whack](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/out-of-whack).

The problem here is that your index and work-tree are intended to match your current commit, except for any work that you have done *since* you ran `git checkout` to change your index and work-tree.  If `git fetch` updates the `refs/heads/` space branch-name to which your `HEAD` is attached, your index and work-tree no longer match your current commit, because your current commit is the one whose hash ID is stored in that branch-name.  (If you *do* manage to get into this state, it's annoying to fix, though it *is* possible.  See [Why does Git allow pushing to a checked-out branch in an added worktree? How shall I recover?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41158057/1256452))

The `git fetch` command has a flag, `--update-head-ok`, that specifically overrides this check.  You should not use it.  The `git pull` code *does* use it, because `git pull` immediately runs a second Git command that will correct the index and work-tree even in these special cases.  Moreover, `git pull` does some pre-`fetch` checks to make sure that that second command won't wreck everything.  Unless you know exactly what you are doing, though, *you* should not use it.

---

<sup>7</sup>If you *do* do this, you're just making extra mental work for yourself, in general.  I recommend not doing this as everyday practice.  Instead, use `git fetch origin && git checkout master && git merge --ff-only`.  I defined an alias, `git mff`, that runs `git merge --ff-only`, that I use to do these things.

Comment: Awesome  explanation. Many of my doubts got cleared. I just got a few short doubts left to ask. `Q1)` If I run `git fetch origin refs/heads/xyz` in GIT before 1.8.4, then this won't update `refs/remotes/origin/xyz` while in 1.8.4 and above this does. Am I right ?

Comment: Q2) From now on , I am assuming git >= 1.8.4.  So, when I do `git fetch origin master:master` , then first my `refs/heads/master` get updated, Then my `refs/remotes/origin/maste`r gets updated. Then git fetch sees an opportunity , that `refs/heads/master`  may/may not be fast forwardly updated and then proceed . Is the order of steps right ?

Comment: Q3) `remote.origin.fetch` setting only control how my remote tracking branches are updated. They don't interfere in updation of corresponding local branches (for them what we mention in command line affects them). Like in `git fetch origin refs/heads/xyz:refs/heads/abc` , git was not supposed to update remotes/origin/xyz , but it sees an oppurtunity and updates it by `remote.origin.fetch` , however , refs/heads/abc  is unaffected by what we write in `remote.origin.fetch`. Am i right ?

Comment: Re Q1: yes. (And remember, we're *assuming* the default `fetch` setting. If you change it to something else, the behavior may change.) Re Q2: Again, I haven't tested this lately (nor in every Git version) and it's possible that there's no *controlled order* for the updates. The internal fetch code changed fairly significantly at several points in Git's evolution, including after 1.8.4. In general, the failure to update any one reference doesn't preclude Git from going on to other references, but I'm not sure what happens in some corner cases.

Comment: Re Q3: assuming a standard `remote.origin.fetch`, yes. If you want, you could experiment with nonstandard `fetch` settings to see what happens if you map, e.g., `refs/heads/xyz` as a source to both `refs/heads/hello` and `refs/heads/world` as a destination, or what happens if you map multiple sources to a single destination. (This also is code that changed over the years, so what you observe from your Git version may be specific to your Git version.)

Comment: Q4) I was trying understanding the last paragraph but have the following doubt. You said - ***"git merge updates the index and work-tree, as if you ran git checkout....get out of whack."*** . Now by index , I think you mean staging area. But how can git merge change index ? staging area needs to be clean before we can merge a branch into another ?

Comment: Re Q4: yes, index = staging-area (and it's also called the *cache*, three names for the one thing). And yes, the index / staging-area must normally be "clean" (i.e., match the `HEAD` commit) before `git merge` will proceed. (I think there is at least one code path where it does not have to be clean, but I'm not sure how to trigger it.)

Comment: Q5) The last thing now. Continuing the above discussion you said ***"... get out of whack"***. How can things get out of whack ? If we allow git fetch to update the current branch too , what can go wrong ? We can always write the code of `git fetch` like don't update the current branch if index not clean else update it. Let our working tree change then. What can go wrong ?

Comment: I included a link in the answer to one case that goes wrong with `git worktree`; follow it to see one example. To see another for yourself, try creating a repository with several commits in it. Check out the tip commit of some branch `B`, run `git status` to observe the "nothing to commit" state, then use `git update-ref refs/heads/B <existing-commit-hash>` to set the branch name to a different commit. Run `git status` again. What changed, and why?

Comment: Hi torek, wanted to verify one thing : If my HEAD is on branch `C` and run `git pull origin A:B` (A,B both branches and this gets successfully executed) , then i am seeing remote tracking branch of A is getting merged into C. I am not seeing remote tracking branch B getting merged into C ? Is this always the case ?

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin: As always, break this down into its two component operations: first Git runs `git fetch`, which updates `FETCH_HEAD`. Then Git runs `git merge` with a `-m` argument to set the merge message, against the commit brought in according to the `FETCH_HEAD` file. The *message generated* for this case probably should read `merge branch 'A' of <url>"`, but it's possible that `git pull` supplies something else as its `-m` argument. The log message is of course arbitrary: if you use `-m` yourself, you can set it to `insert beans into nose`.

Comment: While the `-m` message may matter to future readers, what actually matters to `git merge` is the raw commit hash ID (extracted from `FETCH_HEAD`) and the commit graph at the time. Assuming `git merge` makes a merge commit, the merge commit's two parents will be the current `HEAD` commit, and the commit identified, at this time, by `FETCH_HEAD`. The commits identified by any (local) branch names, if any, are not relevant—the fact that `refs/heads/B` may or may not match the commit hash ID stored in `FETCH_HEAD` is not important to the merging process and result.

Comment: Thnx for reply torek but I am unable to extract my answer from above comments. Let me reframe my question. If I run `git fetch origin A:B` what will `FETCH_HEAD ` point to ? Based on my observation I am getting FETCH_HEAD points to `remote/origin/A`and not `remote/origin/B`. (Assuming fetch is successful)  I wanted to verify that once from you.

Comment: `FETCH_HEAD` and `refs/remotes/origin/A` would indeed contain the same hash ID, until the next `git fetch` (or other operation that overwrites one or both) anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> Here , origin/master needs to be merged in master but this won't be fast forward. git fetch will fail. I don't want force fetch as I don't want to lose my commits C and B also.

That's why you shouldn't use `git fetch` to update the current branch. Use `git pull` either with merge or rebase. Having

```
...--o--o--A   <-- origin/master
            \
             C--B   <-- master
```

you run `git pull origin master` and get here:

```
...--o--o--A-----D   <-- origin/master
            \     \
             C--B--M   <-- master
```

With `git pull --rebase origin master` you get there:

```
...--o--o--A--D   <-- origin/master
              \
              C'--B'   <-- master
```

(Rebase rewrites commits `C` and `B` to `C` and `B`).

I prefer to always use rebase so I have this configuration:

```
git config --global branch.autosetuprebase always
```

That makes git configures rebase for every new branch. For existing branch the change is

```
git config branch.master.rebase true
```

Comment: ***That's why you shouldn't use git fetch to update the current branch.*** , i never said my master is current branch. Also, from ur answer I get that fetch will always lead to fast forward update and hence there seems to be no way with fetch. Hence I have to use git pull only for such scenarios.