# What happens when I pull from a different branch while I am on the master branch

Tags: git

1) In **local** repo, I created and switched to a branch `postacl` by running `git checkout -b postacl`

---

2) Then I ran `git push -u origin postacl`

---

3) From the **remote** repo, while I was still on the `master` branch there, I accidentally ran `git pull origin postacl`. Then I realized that I did not switch to `postacl`.

---

What happened due to the above-mentioned actions?

Comment: Assuming your created a new branch from master and pushed it to remote repo, pulling the changes into master from this newly created repo won't affect anything if you haven't committed and pushed any changes to `postacl`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between 'git pull' and 'git fetch'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7169390/7976758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git pull` means:

1. Run `git fetch`, passing (most of) any additional arguments on to `git fetch`
2. Run `git merge` (default—you can change this), merging the commit(s) brought in via step 1

So this meant:

```
git fetch origin postacl
```

which had your Git call up the Git that you call `origin` and obtain from them their latest commits on their `postacl` branch.  Then, your Git ran:

```
git merge --edit -m <message> <commit-hash-ID>
```

where the `<message>` part is the string:

```
Merge branch 'postacl' of <url> [into <branch>]
```

(using the `<url>` stored with your name `origin`), and the `<commit-hash-ID>` is whatever commit hash ID *their* Git told *your* Git that their `postacl` branch names.  (The `into <branch>` part appears if and only if you are on some branch other than `master`.)

This is almost the same as if you ran:

```
git fetch origin && git merge origin/postacl
```

except that the default merge message in this case would be slightly different.

Note that if you did all this while logged in to some other machine ("the remote repo", as you put it), "your" Git is the one *on* that remote machine, and "their" Git is the one that the remote machine's Git has set as *its* `origin`.

Comment: `So this meant` ... unless the original problem has pull configured to use rebase, in which case the steps would be different.  Also, there may not have been a merge commit at all if the branch doesn't have any commits beyond what `master` already had.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Right: `git merge` might do nothing, or might produce a fast-forward; or `git pull` might be configured to run `git rebase` as its step 2. Had the OP included the *output* from `git pull`, we could say a lot more.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, most likely, you just added a merge commit on top of your local `master` branch.  You may verify this by running `git log` from your `master` branch.  You would probably see a new merge commit, with a commit message mentioning something about a merge.  If you don't see any merge commit, then you need not do anything.  If you *do* see one, then keep reading.

In this particular case, you should be safe just doing a hard reset to remove the merge commit:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

This should nuke that accidental merge commit, leaving your local `master` as it was.  You could also try resetting your local `master` to the tracking branch:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you've simply created a new branch from the master (assuming).

Second, you've pushed without changes and using `-u` changed the branch to track the changes, so whenever you're going to use argument less `git pull` then it will consider `postacl`'s head refs to use as `FETCH_HEAD`.

And at third step, it'll show you something like this:

```
From <url>:<org>/<branch>
 * branch              <tracking_upstream_branch>     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```